# most frequent variable in rows of a dataframe

Tags: r, count, apply, frequency

How can I get a output data frame with most repeated value in each row for its corresponding row ?

```
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1:10), y=seq(1:10), z=sample(1:10), w=sample(1:10), v=sample(1:10))
```

I tried `apply` but it didn't output the correct answer : `apply(df, 1, frequency)`

solved by following :

```
getmode <- function(v) {
   uniqv <- unique(v)
   uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
```

Then

`apply(df, 1, getmode)`

Comment: Try `Mode <- function(x) {
+   ux <- unique(x)
+   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
+ };
> apply(df, 1, Mode)`

Comment: `apply(df, 1, some_function)` and you can find a bunch of `some_function` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode)